# Initialization doesn't call the override class function for property wrapper

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, overriding, property-wrapper

I have a base class and a derived class... the base class has a class function `userDefaultKeyPrefix()` which indicates the user defaults key for user default storage using a wrapper

however the `AdvancedManager` class ends up with the `BaseManager` class value of `userDefaultKeyPrefix()` `"BASE.someVar"` instead of `"ADVANCED.someVar"`

**Why is this happening and how to achieve the desired outcome so the keys are given by the class**

The init of the someVar is called as the Base class, not the Advanced

```
class BaseManager {

    class func userDefaultKeyPrefix() -> String {
        return "BASE"
    }
    
    @UserDefault(userDefaultKeyPrefix() + ".someVar", defaultValue: false) var someVar: Bool

}

class AdvancedManager: BaseManager {

    override class func userDefaultKeyPrefix() -> String {
        return "ADVANCED"
    }
    
}

@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T
    
    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            //let oldValue = wrappedValue
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

---

UPDATE: This bellow works (the key is the "`lazy`") as expected, but defeats the clean code of a property wrapper

```
func prefix() -> String {
    return String(describing: type(of: self))
}

lazy var _someVar = UserDefault(self.prefix() + ".someVar", defaultValue: "DEFAULT")
var someVar: String {
    get {
        return _someVar.wrappedValue
    }
    set {
        _someVar.wrappedValue = newValue
    }
}
```

**Any better solutions are welcome as answer**